# Delete unused groups in Laravel 8

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a group model and I want to delete groups that don't have any member.

How can I get empty groups with eloquent or SQL query ?

```
class Group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'group_name',
        'description'
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

And this is the `User` model code:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use SoftDeletes, Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->last_name.' '.$this->first_name;
    }

    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `whereDoesntHave` work in you situation.

```
 Group::query()->whereDoesntHave('users')->delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`whereDoesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```php
Group::whereDoesntHave('users')->delete();
```

You can make sure that you are deleting the correct groups by running this statement instead:

```php
dump(Group::whereDoesntHave('users')->get());
```